# Use array index to write value to different sheet row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm currently trying to get this piece of code to send events from a google sheet to a google calendar (Credit to Adam McFarland [on this post](http://www.adammcfarland.com/2013/08/09/tutorial-using-google-spreadsheets-to-update-a-google-calendar-our-new-vacation-management-system/)).

My sheet is currently around 300 rows & growing so to speed things up I've set the range to start at row 248.  But this then seems to throw off the part that notes the event as 'done'.   It sets value of "In 2 calendar" to rows 2, 3, 4 & 5?!?

Easy solution would be just to set the range to the whole sheet again but I'm still learning. I'd like to learn what exactly here isn't working correctly, and also a bit more about how iteration works.

```
//mark as entered, enter ID
sheet.getRange(i+2, 32).setValue('In 2 calendar');
```

Complete code below:

```
function pushToCalendar() {
  //spreadsheet variables
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(248,1,lastRow,40);
  var values = range.getValues();   
  var updateRange = sheet.getRange('G1'); 

  var numValues = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {     
    //check to see if name and type are filled out - date is left off because length is "undefined"
    if ((values[i][0].length > 0) && (values[i][2].length > 0)) {
      //check if it's been entered before          
      if (values[i][30] != 'In calendar') {    
        //Declare which calendar ID to use  (IGNORE THIS FOR NOW)                   
        var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('calendarID')

        // if (values [i][3] != 'Tropical 2450 Pontoon'){
        // var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('calendarID')

        //create event https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp#createEvent
        var newEventTitle = values[i][3]+'. '+values[i][2]+'. '+values[i][13]
                  +'. '+values[i][5]+'/'+values[i][6]+'/'+values[i][7]
                  +'. '+values[i][18]+' total, '+values[i][25]+' to pay. '+values[i][0];
        // var newEvent = calendar.createEvent('hello', Date[i][1], Date[i][5]);
        var newEvent = calendar.createEvent(newEventTitle, 
                                            //new Date(values[i][6]),
                                            new Date(values[i][32]),
                                            new Date(values[i][33]));
                                            //{guests:'tures.com.au', sendInvites: true});

        //mark as entered, enter ID
        sheet.getRange(i+2, 32).setValue('In 2 calendar');

      } //could edit here with an else statement
    }
    numValues++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you've already identified the issue. `sheet.getRange(i+2, 32).setValue('In 2 calendar');`, but `i` starts at zero. Instead, create a `startRow` variable and set it to 248. Then iterate it at the end of each for-loop execution. Use the `startRow` variable in place of `i`... `sheet.getRange(startRow+2, 32).setValue...`

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense.  Seems so simple after the fact!